# responsive navigation element of swiper

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, navigation, fixed, absolute

In my react project I have a swiper and I wanna have both the prev and next buttons on top right (and out) of the sliders. I have customized the buttons but I have a problem with them. My problem is that as I changed the buttons positions to the top right corner(position absolute or fixed), when I reduce the width of the screen(max-width: 1350px), two buttons pass each other and prevent the page being responsive. As well in large screens the distance increases disproportionate. I would be so thankful if you help me solve this problem.